# The order of fclose and free

Tags: c, file, free

Should we free memory before closing a file?
For example, I open a file a, alloc an array b, then why should we free b before fclose(a)? What would happen if we do it otherwise?

Comment: Since you did not give any code, I can easily say that there is no relation at all..both ways should result in same behavior...why do you think that they have different behaviour? it is good to give some code or errors.

Answer (score 3):

There is no requirement that you have to `free` the allocated memory before calling `fclose`.

You can:

1. Open file
2. Allocate memory
3. Read the data
4. Close the file
5. Use the allocated memory
6. Deallocate the memory

without any problems.